# Design pattern alternative for factories : classes with different constructors

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory

I am writing an application that can launch new process'. I have identified that these process' will fundamentally differ in two ways, either they can run standalone or depend on an existing process to function. So I therefore have created two abstract classes, inheriting from a base abstract class.

I am trying to work out how to write a factory or other design pattern that will return the class I need depending on a file extension string I give, which will happen at runtime. However I don't think that the factory pattern is a good,sensible fit as these fundamental difference results in differing constructors. I could write myself a huge switch or nested if statement that would work, but for this project I am really trying to increase my c++ knowledge (this is the first time I have used inheritance really).

Say I have my abstract base class :

```
class launchable {
protected:
    std::string              name;
    std::string              directory;
    std::string              path;
    std::string              fileType;
    std::vector<std::string> launchArgs;
    bool                     hasLaunched;
    launchable(std::string _name, std::string _directory,std::string _fileType,std::vector<std::string> _args);
public:
    virtual void             start() = 0;
    virtual void             stop()  = 0;
    virtual void             writeMessage(std::string theMessage) = 0;
    virtual boost::optional<std::string> readMessage()            = 0;
};
```

and then two further abstract classes inheriting from this, firstly a standalone class that starts/stops and writes to its own process:

```
class standalone : public launchable{
protected:
    processManager *manager;
    std::shared_ptr<processManager::launchableProcess> process;
    virtual std::string formatWriteMessage(std::string theMessage) = 0;
    standalone(std::string _name, std::string _directory,std::string _fileType,std::vector<std::string> _args,processManager *_manager);
public:
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop()  = 0;
    void writeMessage(std::string theMessage);
    boost::optional<std::string> readMessage();
};
```

and a dependent class that must start/stop/read/write through a standalone process:

```
class dependent : public launchable{
protected:
    standalone *dependency;
    dependent(std::string _name, std::string _directory,std::string _type,std::vector<std::string> _args,standalone *_dependency);
public:
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop()  = 0;
    void writeMessage(std::string theMessage);
    boost::optional<std::string> readMessage();
};
```

An example concrete standalone, *nix executable that runs on a command line:

```
class executable  : public standalone {
private:
    std::string formatWriteMessage(std::string theMessage);
public:
    using standalone::standalone;
    void start();
    void stop();
};
```

And example concrete dependable, a supercollider patch that must run through a *nix command line interpreter:

```
class supercolliderPatch : public dependent {
public:
    using dependent::dependent;
    void start();
    void stop();
};
```

So ideally what I would want is something like (pseudocode):

```
launchable *sclang = launchableFactory.create("exec",ARGS); // returns a standalone
launchable *patch = launchableFactory.create("supercolliderPatch",sclang,ARGS) // returns a dependable, with dependency set to sclang
```

And these launchable *instance would be stored within a std::vector.

Essentially my question is: am I on a fools errand trying to lump these two concepts of standalone/dependent into one or can the factory pattern work for me?

Comment: You are not fool to lump these two concepts and the factory pattern will work for you. It often involves switch statement. So if you are learning, also consider returning a unique_ptr from your factory. Notice also that it is possible to design a wrapper class that hold the unique_ptr returned by the factory and where the factory is actualy the constructors of this wrapper class. This is known as Parent's or value type polymorphism. It is a kind of implementation of the strategy design pattern. [video Parent's polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BpMYeUFXv8)

Comment: Thanks for the video :) Would there be an argument for letting the factory retain shared ownership by using a shared ptr? I have augmented my create method so that if you create a dependent class it automatically finds the relevant standalone class from the factory's list of objects it has allready created. Or is this bad design?

Comment: This is also a common practice,  if this is a good design depends on how well it fit inside your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract Factory let's you do exactly that: Construct some concrete instance and treat it as it's abstract interface. 
If you can't find a common interface to work with both classes then you might want to reconsider your design, tho it doesn't seem like that's a problem in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at Abstract Factory before but had decided that it wouldn't work - assuming that it was for creation of multiple "products"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, some of the functional programming, but it may have some minimal performance negative impact. Also it requires C++11 or later

```
std::function<shared_ptr<Base>()> funcs[] = { [](){ return shared_ptr<Base>(new A()); }, [](){ return shared_ptr<Base>(new B()); } };
```

Then call:

```
funcs[i]();
```

You can for safety, use something like `array`.

```
std::array<std::function<shared_ptr<Base>()>, 2> funcs[] =
    { [](){ return shared_ptr<Base>(new A()); }, [](){ return shared_ptr<Base>(new B()); } };

(funcs->at(i)();
```

This "array of functions" are something like Abstract Factory that returns a shared pointer of the base class.